# Install libraries on nitrous.io

Tags: nitrousio

I need to install geos, but can't use `sudo` to run `sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev`.  I can download the source `tar` file, but don't I need to adjust the `--prefix` option when I run `./configure`?

What do I need to adjust the prefix to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the prefix, for sure, since you don't have access to the system. You can use $HOME as prefix, or /home/action if you prefer... you can do anything inside user's home directory :)