# Installing lib without sudo (13: Permission denied)

Tags: railstutorial.org, apt-get, nitrousio

I am trying to follow the HARTL tutorial on nitrous.io, trying to install libraries I get the error....

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
```

When I try to enter...

```
apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

How can I run this command without root? I saw some reference to this issue here... [Install libraries on nitrous.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537515/install-libraries-on-nitrous-io) however, I don't understand how prefixing works. I tried to run....

```
/home/action apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev
```

But, get the error...

```
-bash: /home/action: Is a directory
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you chose the Rails box template, you can skip this. You can probably start right out on Section 1.2.3 of Chapter 1.

Comment: Perhaps try and show some code to help explain the answer.

Comment: There isn't really any code to show here; the OP would just have to choose the Rails box when setting up his/her box.

Comment: After speaking with a more informed friend IRL, you are correct and all the gems I need were already installed. Thank you. I actually really like nitrous, although I do feel I didn't understand the tool when I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

`apt` (or `dpkg`, in general) cannot install packages into some user-provided path; packages installed into system paths specified within them.

Link you referred to addresses `configure`, as it accepts `--prefix` argument. It have nothing to do with apt. `configure` usually used to build software from sources.